# How to create a page like this

Tags: wordpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coGGs.jpg)I want to create this page on WordPress and I find it costly to create a page like this using plugins. So help me with some code or files

custom search table with filters and sorts as seen on the image

Comment: Hi, You need to show us something for us to be able to HELP you. We won't provide free code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

unfortunatelly I can't provide you the whole code for solving your case but here are some hints so you can also improve your skills with Wordpress:

take a look at this -> https://saika.li/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-form/

You can also enjoy all bootstrap features to improve your UI: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/